# Not able to maintain values in session

Tags: php, session

Not able to maintain values in session at the client side(Member login).

In the code below, we had stored client id in a session variable. But we can’t access that in `myprofile.php`. So after login, we can’t maintain `myprofile` page.

What could be the error?

```
    case "LOGIN":
    {
                $username   = $_REQUEST['a0'];
                $password   = md5($_REQUEST['a1']);
                $table_name  = "coco_members";
                $count       = $fn->returnColumn($table_name,"count(*) as val","member_uname='$username' and member_pwd='$password' and     member_active='1'");
                if($count>0)
                {
                 $result = $fn->returnColumn($table_name,"member_id","member_uname='$username' and member_pwd='$password' and   member_active='1'");
                }
            else
            {
                $result ="";
            }

            if($result!="")
            {
                $_SESSION['CID'] = $result;
                echo $_SESSION['CID'];
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['CID']="";
                echo "NOK";
            }
    break;   
}
case "GETPOSTS":
{
    $page     = $_REQUEST['page'];
    $activeid = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $count    = $_REQUEST['count'];

    include("includes/client.php"); 
    echo getPosts($page,$activeid,$count); 
    break;`
```

Comment: Setting the `$_SESSION` variable in PHP is _not_ client side.

Comment: have you called `session_start()` before using sessions in each page ?

Comment: Yes, line 2 says as this: @session_start();

Comment: Please help on this...

Comment: Please do not use $_REQUEST. use $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE. It depends on the 'register order' in php.ini what is the last value in there. Also store the fact the user has logged in, in your own 'user has logged in' 'cookie', rather than session variables which 'go away' after a short time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with sessions at some servers. In XAMP it would work prefect but when transferred on server it would not recognize session. Finally I find solution for this, by trails and errors. By creating session.php file and including it at the top of all files that needed session. Just write session_start(); in session.php and that is all.

Dunno if this will help you but it helped me while working on few project that had servers who wouldn't do what they needed to.

EDIT: In 90% percent of my cases, that had this problem, where on free servers so if your working on free server this might fix it.